# Can I define which layout to use inside the view in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

My views all use a layout `views/layouts/application.html.erb`

For some of my views I want to use a diferente layout `views/layouts/page.html.erb`

I know that in the controller I can define `layout:` but my question is if I can define the layout also inside the view itself?

Where else can I set the layout?

Background is that I am using Devise and I want to define a diferente layout for the login page. Devise by default does not give me access to its controllers. I can generate the controllers but doing this brings me into other problems. So my first try is to set the layout without having the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

While you can do it from the view a cleaner way to solve it would be be simply subclassing the devise controller:

```
# app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  layout 'page'
end
```

Then tell devise to route to your custom controller:

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "sessions" }
```